# Why it gives me Type error in that code?

Tags: database, python-2.7, sqlite

Why he gives me (Type error) in that statment 
" address = cur.fetchone()[2]  last = cur.fetchone()[4]  no = cur.fetchone()[5] , while it accept "name = cur.fetchone()[1]" in the code : "

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('myproject.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()
print "Welcome Mr/Hefnawy"
cur.execute('SELECT phone FROM participants')
b = cur.fetchone()[0]
while True:
    a = raw_input("Enter Phone number here : ")
    if a == b :
        cur.execute('SELECT name,address,last_order,no_of_orders FROM    participants WHERE phone = ?',(b, ))
        name = cur.fetchone()[1]
        address = cur.fetchone()[2]
        last = cur.fetchone()[4]
        no = cur.fetchone()[5]
        print "The Costumer is already exist in Paricipants "
        print "To edit the costumer data press (1)", "\n" , "to delet the    costumer press (2)", "\n" , "add new order to the costumer press (3) "
        c = raw_input("Enter your choice here : ")
        if c == "1":
            print "What do you want to edit ? , to edit name press 1 , to edit address press 2 , to edit phone press 3"
            d = raw_input("Enter your choice here : ")
            if d == "1" :
                e = raw_input("New costumer name please ")
                cur.execute('UPDATE participants SET name = ? WHERE phone = ?' , (e , a))
                print "Costumer name has been updated to :", e
                print ""
                conn.commit()
    else:
        print "The costumer is not exist"
        print b
        print a , type(a)
```

Comment: Complete error message please

Answer (score 0):

When you are fetching something from a cursor say for example

```
t = cur.fetchone()
```

you can access the data from t using
     `print t[0],t[1],t[2]` but In your case you are using multiple `cur.fetchone()` which allows you to use `name = cur.fetchone()[1]` that ends the data in the cursor. The second line `address = cur.fetchone()[2]` and the lines that follow it do not have a sql query executed for them to fetch, hence giving you the error. If you want to access the whole row just assign it to a variable and use the variable to get the data.